# linear interpolation using Snowpark between 2 dates

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have table like this, that I already save as snowpark dataframe from previous join operations:

| ID | Customer ID | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-01-20 | 2020-03-01 |
| 2 | BBB | 2020-01-20 | 2020-03-01 |

Then, I'd like to explode on the start_date and end_date with 1 month interval to get an output that looks like this:

| ID | Customer ID | Dates |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-01 |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-02 |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-03 |
| 2 | BBB | 2020-01 |
| 2 | BBB | 2020-02 |
| 2 | BBB | 2020-03 |

Is there any recommendations on how to do it using Snowpark? I am relatively new with Snowpark. I know that we can use sequence and explode functions to do that in pyspark. But I am not sure how to do it in Snowpark. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `table generator` to get the months between your start and end dates :

`DATE_TRUNC(month, start_date)` to get first day of the month.

`ADD_MONTHS` to Adds or subtracts a specified number of months to a date.

```
select ID, CUSTOMER_ID, 
           ADD_MONTHS( DATE_TRUNC(month, start_date) , row_number() over(partition by ID order by null) - 1 ) GENERATED_DATE
from mytable, table(generator(rowcount => 10))
qualify GENERATED_DATE <= end_date
```

Consider increasing the number `rowcount` if the date difference is higher than 10 months.